# Show selected file in php

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

I have a file upload and uploading a image and I want it to show as a thumbnail.

[image]

Here I want to show the Image as a thumbnail.I googled but I didn't got what I want.Please help...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#test').attr('src', e.target.result);
       }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
       }
    }
</script>
```

Still not working...

I Put this code in main body.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<input onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" />
      <img alt="Image Display Here" id="test" src="#" />
  </form>
```

Comment: You're example is using jQuery. You say it doesn't work. If it did work then using jQuery would be an option?

Comment: have you linked to jquery ? does the console give any errors

Comment: Here's the live example of what you were trying : http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/   Are you using HTML5 doctype?

Comment: What browser you using ? That fiddle works for me in Chrome but not in Opera, Might be your browser

Comment: scrub that last comment, does work in opera.

Comment: @Akhilesh B Chandran Its working thanks !! but in chrome my alt not working...

Comment: Better upload the page to some server or paste it as a new fiddle in JSFiddle.net and let us know so that we could put our hands on it to see what's happening. Like @Billy mentioned, are you able to see anything in the Javascript Console window(Ctrl+Shift+J) in Chrome when you run your version? Say like any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<img id="imagePreview">
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="image" class="img" />';
$(function() {
$("#uploadFile").on("change", function()
{
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader           support

    if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
        var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

        reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
            $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
        }
       }
     });
   });
```

[image]